# How to pass variables from react to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, httparty

I am trying to fetch data from a third party API and I have to do a backend fetch.

I have React on frontend and Rails on the backend. I found out about Httparty and hardcoded the url and it fetches the data.

I would like to know how I can pass variable from my React input so that I can use it on the url which is in my controller.

In react I have something like this:

```
class Restaurants extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      restaurants:[],
      inputaddress = ""
    }
```

Now I would like to somehow transfer the `inputaddress` to the controller where I am trying to use Httparty, so, it would look something like `somethirdpartyapi/inputaddress`.

Does it make sense that I want to do this? please help. And where would be the best place to put Httparty?

Comment: The react input sends a get ajax request to the rails server, rails responds with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a request to Rails so that it can take that variable and perform an action with it. To do that you need to define a route (for a `POST` request) and a controller action.

You can do this with one of the following

1. `<form> with a 'submit' <input>` (my favorite)
2. AJAX request
3. Any other regular HTTP request

Comment: Cool. thanks. how would i then get the response from rails back to react so that i can do bunch of stuff with it like render and stuff? i remember in express there was something calld res.locals is there a similar thing in rails?

Comment: You can have a javascript tag with variables you set in there. Like: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript